# How to pass on variables to a modal dialog using jquery?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, modal-dialog

I'm creating a calendar dynamically in rails and I want to open a modal dialog showing the day the user clicked (So I can use a form in there to make a reservation on that specific day).
How can I do that? Here's my code:
BTW, I'm using SIMPLE MODAL (http://www.ericmmartin.com/projects/simplemodal-demos/)

View: (I shorted it)

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>Monday</td>
  <td>Tuesday</td>
  ...
 </tr>
 <tr>
    <% for i in (0..6)    #Weekdays %>
           <td><a href='#' class='basic'><%= @date.day %></a></td></table>
    <% end %>
 <tr/>
</table>

<div id="basic-modal-content">
     <!-- Here's the hidden form that will make the reservation. 
          This is the modal dialog content!. Here is where I need to show the day clicked-->
</div>
```

The Javascript code: (I just open it)

```
$('.basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
    return false;
});
```

Thanks a lot! I hope any of you could help me.

Gus

Comment: I had this problem once myself. Not knowing how to fix it, I created a hidden field somewhere on the page and assigned its value before calling the jquery dialog. Then I accessed the hidden field's value from the dialog. I am sure there is a better way though.

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your quick response!. But I still don't get it right. I can access the hidden field from the dialog as you say, using maybe getElementById(id_hidden_field), but how could I know which value where clicked?. For example:

$('.basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
    #Here! How could I get the variable @date from the main page??
    return false;
});

Answer (score 0):

`.modal()` returns a jQuery object, you could set the html in it like this `.modal().html("Content");`

Comment: Hi! Thanks a lot for your quick response!. But I still don't get it right. I can access the hidden field from the dialog as you say, using maybe getElementById(id_hidden_field), but how could I know which value where clicked?. For example:

$('.basic').click(function (e) {
    $('#basic-modal-content').modal();
    #Here! How could I get the variable @date from the main page??
    return false;
});